# Horizontal Scrolling div with multiple div inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling div with several divs with text inside. The problem is when i try to put the text inside, it overlaps with the div next to it. How can I fix this and make the text bounded within the divs.

Here's a sample code http://jsfiddle.net/znu36yn3/1/

CSS:

```css
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 90px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.popup div { 
    background-color: #8cc63f;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: normal;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.d1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the parent element, you need to use [`white-space: normal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the children elements rather than [`word-wrap: normal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lme424xk/)

```
.popup div {
    white-space: normal; /* Added .. */
    background-color: #8cc63f;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height:1;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

As a side note, the `font` tag is deprecated - don't use it.